# Cant get users home directory to be /var/www svftpd

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

So I have setup my server with svftpd to be able to connect with ftp.
I created a user (ftp_user)

Now I can connect with ftp, but the server shows no files:

it displays: `Index of /` (I guess this is root?) and no files.

I tried to set the home by doing the following 2 things:

`usermod -d /new/home ftp_user` and I added `local_root=/var/www` to my vsftpd conf. Also I chowned the `/var/www` folder to ftp_user. Is there anything I forget?

Comment: Why are you trying to use FTP?  Use `sftp` via SSH which is secure, plain old FTP is **insecure** and **not recommended for any use**

Comment: well thats something to consider indeed, but no the problem I am facing

Comment: No, it's not, and that's why i didn't post this as an answer.  ;)